# MySQL - inserting incremental numbers for each 'group'

Tags: php, mysql

Have this result set below; am trying to insert the red numbers into post_position - start from 1, as many rows as there are for each `topic_id`.

Can this be done using a simple query in phpMyAdmin, or do I need to use PHP? (if I need PHP, can you help with a brief snippet?)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro i think is a worst designed table :( add

```
id
```

for each value;

after make php:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM <table> ORDER BY topic_id, id");
$count = 1;
while($r = mysql_fetch_assc($result){
     if(!isset($topic_id) || $topic_id != $r['topic_id]){
         $topic_id = $r['topic_id];
         $count = 1;
     }
     mysql_query("UPDATE <table> SET post_position = {$count} WHERE `id` = {$r['id'}");
     $count++;
}
```

Comment: That's not the entire table, I've just filtered it down. ;)  It does have a unique id for each row. I'll give your code a test. thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it at the SQL layer with some server-side variables and a bunch of ugly logic in the query itself. But it'd be far easier to do it in PHP.

```
select @last_group := null; @row_num := 0;

select if(@last_group <> grouped_field_in_your_table, @row_num := @row_num + 1, @row_num := 1), 
   other,fields,here
   @last_group := group_field_in_your_table
from ....
```

ugly, but would sort of work.

Comment: Simple state machine. Two vars to keep the current row number and the contents of the grouped field. Any time the grouped field changes, reset the row count to 1.